# Point of impact: circle collision

Tags: c#, geometry, point

I'm doing a school project about robocup where robots are playing football with AI. As everything works fine I am still stuck with something.

The robots are simple spheres drawn from top view. Both player shouldn't be allowed to walk into each other and should get a new updated position on the point of impact.

As the collision handler just checks if they collide or not.. I was hoping if there was a way to detect where the circles collide. So I can update the position of the colliding sphere to the last known non-colliding position so they can't walk trough each other and maybe bounce off.

Comment: Since they're just circles, just calculate the midpoint between the circles' centre points. If the circles have different radii, choose one circle and calculate the point along the line one radius away from its centre.

Comment: @Chris: Even simpler than that Chris; see below.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I was suggesting a simple way to calculate the actual collision _location_ and thus calculate the nearest non-colliding position while (likely) maintaining their relative orientation/angle to each other, not simply whether or not they were colliding. I thought that's what Jesse was asking for.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair - I think your comment is good enough to be an answer.

Comment: @SystemDown Thanks, too bad I instead went the full mile and provided a full implementation (I was bored)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you will need to do is to find the point of intersection between the two circles, which could be two points, one point, or none. This is basically done by solving the equations of the two circles together. Here's the math:

http://www.analyzemath.com/CircleEq/circle_intersection.html

Since this is for school I'll leave the coding to you :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. The coding isn't a problem. Couldn't came up with the formula to do so. Think I can start coding now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

All points on a circle's circumference are the same distacne, the radius, from the center of the circle. This is true for every circle on the playing field.

Therefore: two circles have collided EXACTLY when the distance between their centres is <= the sum of their respectve radii.

Comment: It sounded like Jesse was already picking up _when_ they collided, but asking _where_ the collision occurred.

Comment: What Chris is saying. Collision detection is not the problem. It's finding where the circles intersect in a 2D enviroment to get an X & Y position to put them back on the spot where they didn't collide yet. So they stop moving trough eachother at each side of the circle.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you already marked an answer, but I went and put together a fully functioning piece of code, so maybe you can use it anyway. :) From my comment:

> Since they're just circles, just calculate the midpoint between the
>   circles' centre points. If the circles have different radii, choose
>   one circle and calculate the point along the line one radius away from
>   its centre.

This might be a simple implementation. I created some *very meager* helper classes for it; I would totally encourage extending them, making the structs truly immutable, and all that good jazz, but for now serve okay for demonstration purposes.

So for helper classes:

```
public struct Point
{
    public double X;
    public double Y;

    public double Distance(Point otherPoint)
    {
        double deltaX = this.X - otherPoint.X;
        double deltaY = this.Y - otherPoint.Y;
        return System.Math.Sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("({0}, {1})", X, Y);
    }
}

public struct Polar
{
    public double Radius;
    public double Angle;

    public double X { get { return Radius * System.Math.Cos(Angle); } }
    public double Y { get { return Radius * System.Math.Sin(Angle); } }

    public Point ToCartesian()
    {
        return new Point() { X = X, Y = Y };
    }
}

public class Circle
{
    public double Radius { get; set; }
    public Point Position { get; set; }
}
```

Our meat-and-potatoes class/method is this:

```
public class CollisionResult
{
    public Circle Circle1 { get; private set; }
    public Circle Circle2 { get; private set; }

    public Point Circle1SafeLocation { get; private set; }
    public Point Circle2SafeLocation { get; private set; }

    public Point CollisionLocation { get; private set; }

    public CollisionResult(Circle circle1, Circle circle2)
    {
        this.Circle1 = circle1;
        this.Circle2 = circle2;
    }

    public bool CalculateCollision()
    {
        double distanceFromCentres = Circle1.Position.Distance(Circle2.Position);
        if (distanceFromCentres >= Circle1.Radius + Circle2.Radius)
            return false;

        double angleBetweenCircles = System.Math.Atan2(Circle2.Position.Y - Circle1.Position.Y, Circle2.Position.X - Circle1.Position.X);

        Point midpointBetweenCircles = new Point(){X = (Circle1.Position.X + Circle2.Position.X)/2, Y = (Circle1.Position.Y + Circle2.Position.Y)/2};

        Point circle1Offset = (new Polar() { Radius = Circle1.Radius, Angle = System.Math.PI + angleBetweenCircles }).ToCartesian();
        Point circle2Offset = (new Polar() { Radius = Circle2.Radius, Angle = angleBetweenCircles }).ToCartesian();

        CollisionLocation = midpointBetweenCircles;
        Circle1SafeLocation = new Point(){X = midpointBetweenCircles.X + circle1Offset.X, Y = midpointBetweenCircles.Y + circle1Offset.Y };
        Circle2SafeLocation = new Point(){X = midpointBetweenCircles.X + circle2Offset.X, Y = midpointBetweenCircles.Y + circle2Offset.Y };

        return true;
    }
}
```

Usage might look like:

```
private void CheckCollision(Circle circle1, Circle circle2)
{
    CollisionResult result = new CollisionResult(circle1, circle2);
    if (result.CalculateCollision())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Collision detected at {0}! Safe location for circle 1: {1}, circle 2: {2}", result.CollisionLocation, result.Circle1SafeLocation, result.Circle2SafeLocation));
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Did not collide.");
    }
}

var circle1 = new Circle() {Radius = 5, Position = new Point(){X = 0, Y = 0} };
var circle2 = new Circle() {Radius = 5, Position = new Point(){X = 10, Y = 0} };
var circle3 = new Circle() {Radius = 3, Position = new Point(){X = 0, Y = 1} };
var circle4 = new Circle() {Radius = 5, Position = new Point(){X = 3, Y = 7} };

CheckCollision(circle1, circle2);
CheckCollision(circle3, circle4);
```

Outputs:

```
Did not collide.
Collision detected at (1.5, 4)! Safe location for circle 1: (0.158359213500125, 1.31671842700025), circle 2: (3.73606797749979, 8.47213595499958)
```

I don't know if it's necessary in your case to deal with the complexity of calculating true intersections of two circles (where they would intersect at two points) and such. Likely something along these lines would be sufficient for you. I definitely encourage healthy unit tests and making the classes *proper* beyond what I have here. :)

EDIT: Significantly in this case, and this would depend on what you want to do with it for your application, is that when the circles overlap, it simply calculates the midpoint between them *then* moves each circle *away* from that midpoint their respective radii. So depending on the speed and size of the circles, or how they are moving, it might produce weird results. For example, if you had a big 10 radius circle sitting still, then you throw in a 1 radius circle only 0.5 distance from the big circle's centre, that big circle is going to shift about 9.75 units! If you don't get into big overlapping conditions, then maybe it's not much of an issue. I think at the very least this will give you some *information* about the collision and then *how* you want your circles to react as a result will be up to you.